Whether an isotone bijection from a power set lattice to another sends singletons to singletons
By the work of Paul Cohen (on the continuum hypothesis), one can neither prove nor disprove from the axioms of ZFC that a bijection $f$ from the power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of a set $S$ to the power set $\mathcal{P}(T)$ of a set $T$ implies a bijection from $S$ to $T$.

Question. What if $f$ is also isotone, meaning that if $X \subseteq Y \subseteq S$ then $f(X) \subseteq f(Y)$? More precisely, does an isotone $f$ send singletons to singletons? Or is this also independent from ZFC?

In fact, I don't know of a single example of an isotone bijection from a
power set lattice to another (or even into itself) that is not an order isomorphism (namely, whose functional inverse is not isotone too). This may be relevant, considering that if $f$ is isotone, then $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a singleton for each $y \in T$.
It is not difficult to show that an isotone bijection from one complete
lattice to another need not be an order isomorphism. In a way, I'm asking whether power set lattices are special in this regard.

Do you know the answer for the natural isotone injection instance of your question?

One common way to show the consistency of Luzin's axiom $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$, which is an instance of bijective power sets without bijective underlying sets, is to do almost-disjoint coding from MA+$\neg$CH. In this coding, every subset $A\subseteq\omega_1$ is coded by a set $a\subseteq\omega$, which provides the converse injection. I wonder whether we can find coding sets that make an isotone injection? That would seem natural, based on the how the coding works, but it isn't clear to me how to achieve it.

In regard to my first comment, I guess it's obvious that there are isotone injective self-embeddings $P(S)\to P(S)$ that don't take singletons to singletons. But one could still ask whether, if there is an isotone injection $P(S)\to P(T)$, does this imply $S$ injects into $T$?

@JoelDavidHamkins I don't even know what 'natural isotone injection' means in this context. Is it something related to the independence of CH from ZFC? I'm not familiar with the details of any proof of Cohen's result.

I just meant an injective function from P(S) to P(T) that is isotone. Does this imply that S injects into T? It seems a related and perhaps more tractable version of your question.

But my remarks on almost disjoint coding do refer to the set-theoretic details.

Sorry, I read hastily and linked the adjective 'natural' to 'isotone injection' (rather than to 'instance'). I'll think about your question, I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

My comments on the almost disjoint coding would be aimed at constructing a counterexample.

I might ask the question about isotone almost disjoint coding as a separate we question tomorrow, inspired by this question, if that is alright.

This isn't exactly what you asked, but is related: is there an isotone bijection between powersets which is not induced by a map between the underlying sets (that is, just taking pointwise images)?

I guess almost disjoint coding is always isotone in the upward direction, since a larger coding set will always code a larger subset of $\omega_1$, wrt inclusion. But that direction isn't injective anyway. I was thinking of the other direction.

@MihaHabič If $f$ and $g$ are permutations of $S$, then the assignment $h: X \mapsto S \setminus g[S \setminus f[X]]$ is an order isomorphism of the power set lattice of $S$. Is $h$ induced by a permutation of $S$?

Concerning my last comment, $h$ sends singletons to singletons and is continuous (wrt the order topology induced by set inclusion). So, $h$ is indeed induced by a permutation of $S$.

@MihaHabič No, there is not. This is also shown in my answer.

Just noted a related thread on Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897680/

Regarding the injective isotone map question, there can be no isotone injective map from $P(\kappa)$ to $P(\lambda)$, when $\kappa>\lambda$, since the former has chains of order type $\kappa$, but the latter does not. In particular, this also answers my question about almost-disjoint coding---we cannot find coding sets of subsets $A\subseteq\omega_1$ with $a\subseteq\omega$ that respect inclusion.

Here is a more general fact:
Proposition: Any monotone bijection $f: A \to B$ between two Boolean algebras is an isomorphism.
Claim: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.
Proof of Claim: For all $a \in A$, $0 \leq a \leq 1$ implies $f(0) \leq f(a) \leq f(1)$. Since $f$ is surjective, the result follows. $\square$
Claim: $f(a^c) = f(a)^c$ for all $a \in A$.
Proof of Claim: Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $b \in A$ s.t. $f(b) = f(a)^c$. But then by monotonicity, $f(a \wedge b) \leq f(a) \wedge f(b) = f(a) \wedge f(a)^c = 0$, so $f(a \wedge b) = 0$. As $f(0) = 0$, by injectivity, $a \wedge b = 0$. Similarly, $a \vee b = 1$. Thus, $b = a^c$, i.e., $f(a^c) = f(a)^c$. $\square$
Proof of Proposition: It suffices to show that $f(a) \leq f(b)$ implies $a \leq b$ for all $a, b \in A$. As $f(a) \leq f(b)$, we have $f(a \wedge b^c) \leq f(a) \wedge f(b^c) = f(a) \wedge f(b)^c = 0$, so $f(a \wedge b^c) = 0$ and by injectivity, $a \wedge b^c = 0$, i.e., $a \leq b$. $\square$
Since the lattice of all subsets of a given set is a Boolean algebra, and any (order-)isomorphism between lattices of all subsets clearly has to preserve singletons, the result follows.

+1. I am accepting Emil Jeřábek's answer since it came first. However, I like this answer even more: it makes the proof neater and demonstrates that, after all, power set lattices are not that special with respect to the question raised in the OP.

@SalvoTringali IMHO you should accept the best answer, not the first one.

You can change which answer is accepted, it’s not a once and for all thing. I think his answer deserves it more. But anyway, it’s up to you.

How do we know that our isotone bijection preserves meets? This is required to be a boolean algebra morphism and you use this fact in your proof of the claim that it preserves compliments. I suspect I'm just missing something but this proof doesn't make sense to me.

@Keith In the proof of their 2nd claim, David Gao is using that $f(a \land b) \leq f(a) \land f(b)$, not that $f(a \land b) = f(a) \land f(b)$.  This follows from $f$ being isotonic, plus the fact that $a \land b \leq a$ and  $a \land b \leq b$.

Yes, such a mapping necessarily sends singletons to singletons.
Let $f\colon\mathcal P(S)\to\mathcal P(T)$ be a monotone bijection (or more generally, a surjective strictly  monotone function). By monotony, $f(\varnothing)\subseteq f(X)\subseteq f(S)$ for all $X\subseteq S$, hence using the surjectivity of $f$, $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and $f(S)=T$. Also, as noted in the question, $f$-inverses of singletons must be singletons: if $f(X)=\{t\}$, we must have $X\ne\varnothing$; if we further assume for contradiction that there exists $\varnothing\ne X'\subsetneq X$, then $\varnothing\ne f(X')\subsetneq\{t\}$, which is impossible.
Thus, there is $S'\subseteq S$ and a bijection $g\colon S'\to T$ such that $f(\{s\})=\{g(s)\}$ for all $s\in S'$. But then by monotony, $\{t\}\subseteq f(S')$ for all $t\in\operatorname{im}(g)=T$, i.e., $f(S')=T=f(S)$, which implies $S'=S$.
Furthermore, we have $f(X)=g[X]$ for all $X\subseteq S$, hence $f$ is an order isomorphism. To see this, note that for any $s\in S$, $f(S\smallsetminus\{s\})$ includes $f(\{s'\})=\{g(s')\}$ for all $s'\ne s$, but it is strictly contained in $T=f(S)$, hence $f(S\smallsetminus\{s\})=T\smallsetminus\{g(s)\}$. Then for any $X\subseteq S$, we have $\{g(s)\}\subseteq f(X)\subseteq T\smallsetminus\{g(s')\}$ for all $s\in X$ and $s'\notin X$, whence $f(X)=g[X]$.

I guess you mean $S' \subseteq S$. Apart from that, awesome!

Let me just add for my future self that $f(S) = T$: being isotone and surjective implies that f maps the max of the power set lattice of S (that is, S) to the max of the power set lattice of T (that is, T). So, $T = f(S')$ yields by injectivity that $S'=S$.

I added that point to the answer to make it more self-contained.
